# How to initialize class with list in?

Tags: c#, list

Basic question but I cant find anwser anywhere, I have 2 classes:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<Chapter> Chapters{ get; set; }
}

public class Chapter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

How do I add to or initialize this? I have tried:

```
 var books = new List<Book>();

        books.Add(new Book()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Category = "test",
            Title = "Book1 test",
            Chapters = new Chapter() { Id = 1, Title = "A"},
                       new Chapter() { Id = 2, Title = "B" }
        });
```

But I'm getting an error: Invalid initializer member declarator?

Comment: Should Answers be Chapters?

Comment: yup they should, will edit

Comment: its the chapters initialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want

```
Chapters = new List<Chapter>() 
               {
                  new Chapter() { Id = 1, Title = "A"},
                  new Chapter() { Id = 2, Title = "B" }
               }
```

Instead of:

```
Answers = new Chapter() { Id = 1, Title = "A"},
          new Chapter() { Id = 2, Title = "B" }
```

1. Your `Book` class doesn't have  a property named `Answers`
2. You need to create a new collection and place the initializations (`new Chapter() { ... }`) inside of the collection initializer.

Comment: sry, yes see above, should be Chapters - e.g. Book should contain Chapters that relate to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you give `Book` a constructor that initializes `Chapters`:

```
public Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        Chapters = new List<Chapter>();
    }

    // properties
}
```

You will be able to use the collection initializer syntax:

```
var book = new Book()
{
    Id = 1,
    Category = "test",
    Title = "Book1 test",
    Chapters = { new Chapter() { Id = 1, Title = "A" },
                 new Chapter() { Id = 2, Title = "B" } }
};
```

Note that if you don't initialize `Chapters` in the constructor this is still legal, however it will throw a `NullReferenceException` at runtime.

Comment: I think you can only use that initializer syntax right after the initialization: `Chapters = new List<Chapter>() { new Chapter()..., ... }`

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin You can also use it as I've shown. [Try it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3dSaUd).

Comment: I did try it in LINQPad and it didn't work, but now that I included the full example it does work. I guess I have some learning to do.

Answer (score 0):

Selman22 has one answer. Another might to be initialize the list on instantiation of your object:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<Chapter> Chapters{ get; set; }

    public Book()
    {
        Chapters = new List<Chapter>();
    }
}
```

It's not really an IList anymore, it's just a List. One could always override it though.